# Displaying forms one next another [JS]

Tags: javascript

I'm just doing a short form with 2 questions. I want the second one to appear onclick of the submit button of first question. I've tried several things but doesn't works :/
It seems to reload the page everytime i click on the submit button.
I begin so maybe it's a really stupid error.

Thanks !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="question1">
        <h2>Salamèche est-il de type feu ?</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui1" value="oui" >
                <label for="oui1" class="oui">OUI</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non1" value="non">
                <label for="non1" class="non ">NON</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form id="question2">
        <h2>Tiplouf est-il de type plante ?</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui1" value="oui" >
                <label for="oui2" class="oui">OUI</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non1" value="non">
                <label for="non2" class="non ">NON</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <form id="question3">
        <h2>Tiplouf est-il de type plante ?</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui1" value="oui" >
                <label for="oui3" class="oui">OUI</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non1" value="non">
                <label for="non3" class="non ">NON</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript

```
function changeform(x){
    let nextForm = x + 1;
    for (i=0; i <= x; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).addEventListener('submit', function() {
            $('question' + i).css('display','none');
            $('question' + nextForm).css('display','block');
        });
    }
}

function checked(x) {
    for (i=0; i <= x; i++) {
        var oui = 'oui'+i;
        var non = 'non'+i;
        console.log(oui);
        $(oui).addEventListener('click', function() {
            $(oui).className = 'cheked';
        });
        $(non).addEventListener('click', function() {
            $(non).className = 'cheked';
        });
    }
}

checked(3);
changeform(3);
```

Comment: yes, submitting a form will make the page reload, or you should add `type="get"` to the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

`submit` event always reloads the browser window to stop that write

```
document.getElementById(i).addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // this won't let submit action to reload window
  $('question' + i).css('display','none');
  $('question' + nextForm).css('display','block');
});
```